# C++ How to implement this code into the heap properly

Tags: c++, class

I am working on a class assignment to create three classes nested inside each other. I need to make constructors and deconstructors for each that have a message that goes along with them. Finally, I need to create an instance of each class using new and call the display() function to show their message, followed by delete.

I have completed the assignment but in the wrong way, and I am confused about how I can properly put the code into the heap instead of the stack (as I was advised by my course tutor).

This is what I started with: (this code seems to work well, but does not fulfill the assigned project)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Hen   {
public:
    Hen();
    ~Hen();
    string display(void)    {
        return ("Im a Hen");
    }
    class Nest;
    friend Nest;
    class Nest  {
    public:
        Nest();
        ~Nest();
        string display(void)    {
            return ("Im a Nest");
        }
        class Egg;
        friend Egg;
        class Egg   {
        public:
            Egg();
            ~Egg();
            string display(void)    {
                return ("Im an egg");
            }
        };
    };
};

Hen::Hen()  {
    cout << "I construct Hens" << endl;
}

Hen::~Hen() {
    cout << "I deconstruct Hens" << endl;
}

Hen::Nest::Nest()   {
    cout << "I construct Nests" << endl;
}

Hen::Nest::~Nest()  {
    cout << "I deconstruct Nests" << endl;
}

Hen::Nest::Egg::Egg()   {
    cout << "I construct Eggs" << endl;
}

Hen::Nest::Egg::~Egg()  {
    cout << "I deconstruct Eggs" << endl;
}

int main()  {
    Hen hone;
    Hen::Nest none;
    Hen::Nest::Egg eone;
    string h, n, e;
    h = hone.display();
    n = none.display();
    e = eone.display();
    cout << h << "\n" << n << "\n" << e << endl;
}
```

Where I am stuck is when I try to implement my code inside the heap, it seems to break by the second class:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Hen   {
public:
    void display()  {
        cout << "Im a Hen" << endl;
    }
    class Nest;
    friend Nest;
    class Nest  {
    public:
        void display()  {
            cout << "Im a Nest" << endl;
        }
        class Egg;
        friend Egg;
        class Egg   {
        public:
            void display()  {
                cout << "Im an egg" << endl;
            }
        };
    };
};

int main()  {
    Hen *hone = new Hen();
    Hen::Nest *none = new Nest();
    hone -> display();
    none -> display();
    
}
```

Question 1:
If I remove all the information related to nest, the program runs Hen just fine and returns the "I'm a hen" statement. But, when I add in nest, the warning I recieve is
"error: expeected type-specifier before 'Nest'
Hen::Nest *none = new Nest();"

I do not understand what I am doing wrong as I did the exact same process for Hen and it worked. I do know that the error must be in the way Nest gets called through hen?

I apologize if this question is obvious, but I am just starting c++ and do not understand why I am getting these messages...
Thanks for your help!

Comment: `Hen();` is not a constructor, it's a promise you'll create one, which you don't, so you get a linker error. Try: `Hen() { };`

Comment: AHHH thank you!! that is one problem down! I see that I was not pulling the constructor from the first set of code into the second now. That makes way more sense though.

Comment: please one question per question

Comment: You need to specify the entire qualified name when using `new` as well.

Comment: Thank you, you beautiful people! haha fixed all my problems in less than 5 minutes. I added Hen:: to the second Nest and it works!